# Tuleap-Docker : Make autoload-docker return error

Tags: docker, makefile, centos7, autoload, tuleap

i'm working on a tuleap project that's run in a docker container , i added new classes and i want to apply a refresh to the autoload file so
this the Link that help me to do this,

https://tuleap.net/doc/en/developer-guide/autoload.html

But when i execute

> make autoload-docker

I have this error

> docker:unauthorized authentication required

Any one can help me to resolve this issue ?Thx.marwen

Comment: are you able to run docker commands like `docker run helloworld` or do you need `sudo` ?

Comment: Hi, i'm connected as root :)

Comment: According to google, it seems related to an issue with authenticating against the docker hub. Are you able to run `docker pull enalean/tuleap-dev-swissarmyknife:2` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response , but i guess i found the solution , it's about from where we clone the  tuleap project from the beginning ,i think there is two ways to clone it , from gerrit (the dev one) or from git (the stable one) , so i clone from gerrit and i add the my login and my password :)